@capacitor-firestore/firebase plugin - ArrayUnion - how to add entry to an existing array
I'm using this plugin for my ReactJS + Capacitor project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-firebase/firestore#getcollection
However, I don't see any equivalent of arrayUnion in their documentation. I'm trying to add a new entry to an existing array in Firebase, but I can't figure out the correct syntax to do it. I will appreciate any help, thank you.

This is not yet supported but planned for 2025. Check out this GitHub issue as reference: https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/issues/443
